# NodeJS trying to use a URL inside of a fs.createfilestream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a post request onto my api, the api works perfectly ( I am able to post files, but not through a url), but now I'm trying to post through an url.

this is the code I have now, I removed some lines that aren't relevant to the question or were for testing.

```
    request({
                url: url + "gettoken"
                , json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                user = body;
                var rs = fs.createReadStream(up.url);
                var ws = request.post(url + "upload?token=" + `${user.token}&key=${user.key}&filename=${filename}`);
                ws.on('drain', function () {
                    rs.resume();
                });
                rs.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(filename);
                });
                ws.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.error('cannot send file ' + err);
                });
                rs.pipe(ws);
            })
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: What is `up.url`? `fs.createReadStream` only works for (local) files.

Comment: up.url is the url I'm using it is returned somewhere, the fs.createReadstream is only used as that is the way I found out how to do post requests, but if there is an other way, that would be possible too, but I have no idea what I could do

Comment: `fs.createReadStream` is meant to read files, not to make POST requests, that's what the `request.post()` is for. Do you mean that you want to download a file from `up.url` and subsequently _upload_ that file to `url +"upload?..."`?

Comment: yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea is to upload a file that's located at `up.url` to another server at `url + "upload?..."`.

Since `fs.createReadStream` is meant to read local files, and not URL's, you need something that can create a stream from a URL (or rather, retrieve that URL and stream the response).

You can also use `request` for that:

```
request({
  url:  url + "gettoken",
  json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
  const user = body;
  const rs   = request.get(up.url);
  const ws   = request.post(url + "upload?token=" + `${user.token}&key=${user.key}&filename=${filename}`);

  rs.on('end', function () {
    console.log(filename);
  });
  ws.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('cannot send file ' + err);
  });

  rs.pipe(ws);
});
```

Typically, file uploads work through `multipart/form-data`, but your code doesn't suggest that being used here. If it is, the code would become something like this:

```
const ws = request.post(url + "upload?token=" + `${user.token}&key=${user.key}&filename=${filename}`, {
  formData : {
    the_file : rs
  }
});
// no `rs.pipe(ws)`
```